# Typescript: conditionally mark an object property as optional?

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g.:

```
type Foo = {
    'a': string,
    'b': undefined,
};

type Bar<T extends keyof Foo> = {
    foo: Foo[T],
};

const bar1: Bar<'a'> = { foo: 'a' }; // ok
const bar2: Bar<'b'> = { foo: undefined }; // ok
const bar3: Bar<'b'> = {}; // Property 'foo' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Bar<"b">'.
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUDkBDHALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGk2xwCMioBXagEwgDMaEbowC+AbnTpQkKACE85ADwAVKBAAewCDxJQA1hBBw+sBAD5kaJlj4Ji8OAG1lAXVET0AYzjUyUFgoAjMTySvg4FiioULZwxOFQ4l4+fgHkAEwhCoqsEZbRscRcvALUQokS3r7A-goAzFlhbJFo4kA

In this example, I want the `foo` property to be optional if its value is `undefined`. In other words, I want `{ foo: undefined }` and `{}` to be interchangeable.

In my actual code, I have API handlers that conditionally return different fields. If a field is not needed, I want to omit it instead of having to define it as `undefined`.

One way to fix this is:

```
type Bar<T extends keyof Foo> = Foo[T] extends undefined
  ? { foo?: undefined }
  : { foo: Foo[T] };
```

However, if a lot of fields are optional, then the conditional can become very long. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just [`foo?: Foo[T]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=31&pln=11&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUDkBDHALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGk2xwCMioBXagEwgDMaEbowC+AbnTpQkKACE85ADwAVKBAAewCDxJQA1hBBw+sBAD5kaJlj4IA-MXhwA2soC6oiegDGcamSgWBQBGYnklfBwLFFQoWzhiSKhxHz8AoPIAJjCFRVYoy1j44i5eAWohZIlff2BAhQBmHIi2aLRxIA)?

Comment: "*However, if a lot of fields are optional, then the conditional can become very long*" - will it? You'll probably use intersection types, and one conditional per property.

Comment: @Emissary Because that would allow `bar0: Bar<'a'> = {}` which the OP wants to prevent

Comment: ah okay, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Foo = {
    'a': string,
    'b': undefined,
}

type Bar<T extends keyof Foo> = {
    propOne: Foo[T],
    propTwo: Foo[T]
};

type UndefinedBarKeys<T extends keyof Foo> = {
  [K in keyof Bar<T>]: Bar<T>[K] extends undefined ? K : never 
}[keyof Bar<T>];

type BetterBar<T extends keyof Foo> =
    Foo[T] extends undefined
    ? { [K in keyof Pick<Bar<T>, UndefinedBarKeys<T>>]?: Foo[T] }
    : Bar<T>;

const bar1: BetterBar<'a'> = { propOne: 'asdf', propTwo: 'qwerty'};
const bar2: BetterBar<'b'> = { propOne: undefined, propTwo: undefined };
const bar3: BetterBar<'b'> = {};
```